# Did Rav Papa issue a halachic ruling in order to benefit financially?

Tags: rabbis, maseches-shabbos, chazal, bal-tashchit-waste, maharsha

In the Gemara [Shab. 140b](https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.140b.9?lang=bi&p2=Chidushei_Agadot_on_Shabbat.140b&lang2=bi) Rav Papa is recorded saying that one who drinks wine while able to drink beer violates “ba’al tashchit”. Maharsh”a comments that Rav Papa’s disapproval of consuming wine instead of beer was due to personal bias since he had profited handsomely by beer manufacture (Rav Papa was a brewer).

1- Chazal are known to have been individuals that were extremely refined in their character traits including having pure intentions, so how could the Maharsha have written such an explanation?

2- Why did the Maharsha write this explanation? Was there a difficulty he was trying to resolve?

Comment: *"Chazal ... were extremely refined in their character traits"* - where do you take it from?

Comment: *"Chazal ... were extremely refined in their character traits"* - where do you take it from? Many Gemara's that describe their behavior.

Comment: @AlBerko Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/59921/can-one-cite-divrei-torah-in-the-name-of-a-rabbi-who-has-gone-astray  https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/86888/is-one-allowed-to-learn-a-book-written-by-a-rabbi-who-was-accused-and-convicted https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/35725/learning-torah-from-a-confirmed-sinner

Comment: @Gavriel What an interesting question? The Maharitz Chayos's mechudash derech halimud doesn't seem so mechudash now, does it? :)

Comment: To further bolster this question, I seem to recall a Gemara in late Chullin where it questions Rava’s ruling regarding Shiluach HaKan as giving the appearance of personal bias and explains that he acted in such a way as to avoid any such concerns.

Comment: See [this](https://seforimblog.com/2010/04/marc-shapiro-more-on-chaim-bloc/) post, s.v. “Since I mentioned”, by Prof. Marc Shapiro.

Comment: A personal bias influencing someone's perspective is not at all the same as deliberately making a fraudulent legal ruling for personal gain. The most reasonable reading is that the Maharsha was discussing the former, not the latter. You see a similar pro-beer bias phenomenon in *P'sachim* 107a, "רב אשכחיה רב הונא דקדיש אשיכרא אמר ליה שרי אבא למיקני איסתירי משיכרא".

Comment: Please explain, given your assumption, how could Maarsh"a possibly criticize R' Papa, overriding a lot of Mitzvos and presenting himself as a sinner - so it seems to be a [sort of a] circular reference - if all Rabbis are good, so Maarsha can't criticize R"P if they are not, they both are a bit of sinners.

Answer (score 3):

### Background:

The gemara you're referencing is part of a series on [Shabbos 140b](https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.140b.5-19?lang=bi&p2=Steinsaltz_on_Shabbat.140b&lang2=bi) about  Rav Chisda giving sound economic advice.

- For example: since bundles of vegetables & sticks all cost the same, Rav Chisda suggests that one should buy a long bundle to get more bang for their buck.
- In the middle of Rav Chisda's list of economic advice, Rav Papa chimes in with some seemingly economic advice of his own, saying 
  "if someone could drink beer and drinks wine, he transgresses Bal Tashchis."
- To which the gemara rejects this, stating that it is more important for one to not to harm their body (ie drink wine) than save a few dollars (by drinking beer).

As you pointed out, **The Maharsha**'s [commentary](https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.140b?lang=bi&p2=Chidushei_Agadot_on_Shabbat.140b.3&lang2=bi&w2=all&lang3=en) seems to suggest that Rav Papa's opinion was due to his own benefit or personal bias.

### Responding to the Maharsha

The **[Rashash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samuel_Strashun)** (1794-1872) is quoted in [this article](https://www.kipa.co.il/%D7%99%D7%94%D7%93%D7%95%D7%AA/%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A9%D7%AA-%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%95%D7%A2/%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A9%D7%AA-%D7%9C%D7%9A-%D7%9C%D7%9A/%D7%9E%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A2-%D7%9E%D7%96%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%90%D7%AA-%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%99-%D7%A8-%D7%A4%D7%A4%D7%90-%D7%91%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%95%D7%9D-%D7%9E%D7%A1%D7%9B%D7%AA-%D7%9C%D7%A4/) as explaining the Maharsha's comment on Rav Papa as follows:

(translation: mine)

> ואני אומר על פירושו (של המהרש"א) ולאו מילתא היא דמאי יענה על ר' חסדא (מאי נוגע בדבר היה) דהאי "ולאו מילתא היא" שב גם כן על דבריו, ואולי דלזה כוון ר' פפא לעיל ([קי"ח ב'](https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.118b.8?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) באומרו לדידי חשדן ולא הוה בי, כי יש שהיה חושדין אותו כפירוש המהרש"א
>
> And I say on (the Maharsha's) commentary that it's not really anything, because what is Rav Papa answering to Rav Chisda (ie what incentive did Rav Papa have in this) and this "לאו מילתא היא" can also apply on his words, and perhaps this was Rav Papa's intention earlier ([Shabbos 118b](https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.118b.8?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) where he says 'they suspected me and there was nothing of it,' because there were those who were suspicious of him, as the Maharsha writes.
>
> הרש"ש מסביר, שאולי דבריו של רב פפא על כך שחשדו בו לשוא, מוסבים על הסבר המהרש"א לדבריו בנוגע לשכר, שאמר זאת כדי שיקנו ממנו שכר
>
> The Rashash explains that perhaps the talk about suspicion of Rav Papa was in vain, explaining the understanding of the Maharashah's with regards to things dealing with beer, that Rav Papa said this so people would buy beer from him.

My understanding of this is that the Maharsh"a is saying that Rav Papa **WASN'T** giving this advice for his own benefit; however, there were those who were sometimes a little suspicious of Rav Papa and his business dealings (see Rav Papa's [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rav_Papa) for background and also this [kipa.co.il article](https://www.kipa.co.il/%D7%99%D7%94%D7%93%D7%95%D7%AA/%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A9%D7%AA-%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%95%D7%A2/%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A9%D7%AA-%D7%9C%D7%9A-%D7%9C%D7%9A/%D7%9E%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A2-%D7%9E%D7%96%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%90%D7%AA-%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%99-%D7%A8-%D7%A4%D7%A4%D7%90-%D7%91%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%95%D7%9D-%D7%9E%D7%A1%D7%9B%D7%AA-%D7%9C%D7%A4/)) and if the topic was about beer-- even if Rav Papa was giving genuine advice!-- these people would suspect him of having an ulterior motive.

Comment: This Rashash seems to be taking very dochak read of the Maharsha

Comment: @JoshuaPearl I don't disagree- I think it's written in light of him being bothered by the same question as the OP