# Torah-teaching of Rav Edelstein zt"l: enjoy your learning

Tags: sources-mekorot, torah-study, chinuch-education

I've heard a shiur from Rabbi Daniel Glatstein on the teachings of [Rav Gershon Edelstein zt"l](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershon_Edelstein) in which Rav Edelstein zt"l describes what the obligations of a teacher of Torah should have in mind when teaching. Rav Edelstein z"tl is supposed to have said that:

> The responsibily of a Rebbi is not just to teach Torah, but that the talmidim get joy and satisfaction out of their learning. If the student(s) does not enjoy their learning, it is impossible or very hard for them to continue. Yiras Shamayim alone, without enjoyment of learning or interest in the learning will not do the job.

Rav Edelstein zt"l would say that the propery way in which a Rebbi should give a shiur to his students, is that the smartest student will get the point of the shiur very easy, without any problem. With minimal effort. Why, because

> the "weaker student" must feel that at least they are getting
> something from the shiur. That they are happy with their "cheilek".

Does anyone know where to find these "tips and tricks" of Rav Edelstein zt"l on learning and teaching Torah?

Comment: Isn't the first sentence of this post an answer to the question?

Comment: To ask Rabbi Glatstein? Perhaps. But I think this forum is more suitable for this and the most efficient way.

Comment: I mean the cited shiur is a source for the quotations.

Comment: I understand. But with all due respect. I think the original place where this is stated, is better.

Comment: Did R' Glatstein give you reason to believe that the quotations are from a publication of some sort? If so, any information about that that you can add to the question would make it easier to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

B"H, with the help of the office of Rav Glatstein, I've got hands on the original source from these teachings. The sefer is called [קונטרס יסודות החינוך מרבותינו גדולי ישראל שליט"א](https://hebrewbooks.org/49723) (maybe it could also be seen as a pamphlet, rather than a sefer).

The entry is called: Maran Rosh Yeshivah. The great Rabbi Gershon Edelstein Shlita. It can be found starting at page 9 of the pamphlet.

> אלא שבאמת יש בעיה אחת, כי לעומת האהבה של תורה ומצוות, יש דברים אחרים
> שבאים מחמת אהבת העולם הזה המושכים את הלב, יש כל מיני דברים שמושכים
> ומעניינים מאד, שהם כאילו תחליפים לתורה ולעבודה ולכל המעשים הטובים,
> היצר הרע ממציא המצאות חדשות לבקרים, שיש מהם הנמצאים בקירוב מקום בבית
> פנימה . והדברים ידועים כי אלו שהלימוד שלהם זה מתוך יראה בלי מתיקות, אם
> חסר להם ה"אשריך בעולם הזה" ששייך בתורה, כפי שאנו רואים ברוך השם שיש
> אושר כזה להרבה בני תורה, רבים מאלו שחסר להם את המתיקות הזו, הרי הם
> נמשכים אחר מכשירים אסורים, שגורמים אסונות כאלה שאין לשער ואין לתאר.
> חושבני כי הדברים ידועים, ואיני צריך לדבר על כך ברבים

> [...]

> אמנם בכל כיתה יש כמה ילדים טובים, שמבינים היטב את הדברים שנלמדים, והם
> אוהבים את המלמד, שמעולם לא פגע בהם, ומאחר שלא היתה קפידה עליהם אף פעם,
> יכולים הם להצליח. אבל ילדים אחרים שאינם טובים כל כך, שנפגעו מהקפידה של
> המלמד, הרי הם מקבלים דמות שלילית, ומפסיקים להעריך את המלמד, כי ילד קטן
> אינו מבין למה מקפידים עליו, ומה רוצים ממנו, וכבר אינו מרוכז, ואינו
> קולט את תלמודו

> לבד מזאת, בין ילדי הכיתה יש גם תלמידים חלשים, שהמלמד צריך להתמסר אליהם יותר
> בסבלנות, זו עבודה קשה להיות כמו רבי פרידא שהובא עליו בגמרא (עירובין נד ב, ) שהתמסר מאד
> לתלמידו, בוודאי צריכים שתהיה סבלנות להסביר לילדים חלשים .
>
> אך הבעיה היא שיש מחנכים שרוצים ללמד עם רמה גבוהה, כי מלמד שהוא בעל
> רמה, הרי הוא יכול לתת שיעורים ברמה גבוהה, והוא נהנה מהרמה שהוא נותן,
> ונהנה מהתלמידים המצוינים שמבינים את דבריו, אבל מאידך התלמידים שאינם
> מצוינים, לא יוכלו להצליח ברמה כזאת .
>
> ושמעתי מכבר שיטה פדגוגית ידועה, כיצד צריכה להיות רמת אמירת השיעור בפני
> תלמידים. הנה תלמידי השיעור נחלקים לשלשה סוגים, מצוינים, בינוניים
> וחלשים, ומגיד השיעור צריך לתת דעתו שכל התלמידים ברמותיהם השונות יפיקו
> תועלת מן השיעור .
>
> לכן הטוב והמועיל ביותר הוא שרמת השיעור תהיה כזו ש: התלמידים המצוינים
> יוכלו להבין את הדברים בנקל ללא שום מאמץ, עד שיהיו יכולים להמשיך לבד את
> מה שהרב רוצה לומר - לרוב פשיטות הדברים אצלם. וכן צריך לראות שהתלמידים
> הבינוניים יוכלו בריכוז ומאמץ להבין את כל השיעור, ואם לא בשעת השיעור
> עצמו לכל הפחות בחזרת השיעור. וכמו כן יש לראות שגם התלמידים החלשים
> יפיקו תועלת מן השיעור, שיבינו לכל הפחות חלק מועט מהדברים שנאמרו
> בשיעור, כי כאשר הם רואים שגם הם קולטים קצת ומקבלים משהו מהשיעור, יש
> להם במה לשמוח, והם שמחים בחלקם במה שיש להם, וכמובן יחד עם זה צריכים
> לתת להם את העידוד כדי שלא יתייאשו, לומר להם שגם זה מספיק בשבילם,
> והציונים שהם קיבלו במבחנים גם הם טובים עבורם .
>
> אם השיעור הוא ברמה יותר גבוהה מזו, התוצאות הם לא טובות, כי המצוין צריך
> להתאמץ שלא כהרגלו, וכן הבינוני סובל וכבר אינו יכול, והחלש נשבר כשאינו
> מבין כלום מן השיעור

Comment: It's a great source - I quoted it here on a related subject: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/124013/22152

Comment: Wow, indeed a great source. Thanks for pointing to it in another answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here you can find teachings and transcribed English shiurim from R' Edelstein ztz"l to no end:

https://www.dirshu.co.il/category/%d7%94%d7%95%d7%a8%d7%93%d7%95%d7%aa-%d7%a2%d7%9c%d7%95%d7%a0%d7%99%d7%9d/darkei-hachizuk/

A large number of them deals with these topics.

Once I started to index them and upload to Google Drive. These are some of them which deal with limud haTorah:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CQZWQSWhW_-Cdb4-tnBcjyvWUytNpvJF/view?usp=drive_link

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Po6ItVv_rQUartd7me_GkYcDru3z42QB/view?usp=drive_link

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Lzxf9LUgfjxuxdv2LnGr_vzXPLFBgwIQ/view?usp=drive_link

https://drive.google.com/file/d/10bcmOV15kyPpwIDhn1ixAf-6DLWMsZgi/view?usp=drive_link