# Choosing a Rebbi

Tags: torah-study, rebbe-talmid-muvhak

What are some of the considerations one should take into account when choosing a Rebbi? What does it mean that your Rebbi is supposed to be like a Malach?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/108997/6592

Comment: http://torahweb.org/torah/2011/parsha/rsch_mishpatim.html

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Mordechai and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: See my answer there - https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/124013/22152