# CYLOR and Mesorah

Tags: halacha-theory, posek-psak-decisor-ruling, mesorah-tradition, communities

Assume that someone has a she'elah, however their local rabbi does not follow their mesorah. How would one approach the issue of a psak?

For example, let's say my LOR is a Chabad shaliach and I need to ask x. Assuming that my mesorah holds y but Chabad holds z, I will be doing something which violates my mesorah.

Comment: Asei Lcha Rav. My Rabbi told me that when he lived out of town and was uncomfortable with the Rabbis there he called his rabbis or sent his questions via FedEx.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/34314/how-to-choose-your-rebbi/34357#34357

Comment: Not sure I understand; if you know the answer (since you claim you know your Mesora) then why are you asking the Rov?

Comment: @DannySchoemann - He doesn't know the answer to a specific question. He just knows that the one he's asking generally doesn't have the same "mesorah", I assume, regarding other questions. Of course, my question, is why ask this rav anything, if you have in mind beforehand that you wouldn't follow his answer, specifically because he doesn't follow your mesorah? And, perhaps, the answer to your question WOULD agree with your mesorah, anyway? Isn't there some general rule that if you ask p'sak from a rav, you're obligated to follow unless you know that he is outrightly wrong?